# How to draw an icon?

Tags: objective-c, icons, appkit

I am trying to present an icon on the main view of an Objective-C macOS application.
I can choose an image from the list of system images in the xib file but I want to show an icon from the Assets.xcassets AppIcon collection.
How can I do this?
The icon shows on the main view but with what looks like a default document icon.

From the .h file

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *textfield;
    IBOutlet NSImageView *iconView;
}
- (IBAction)seed :(id)sender;
- (IBAction)generate:(id)sender;
@end
```

In the awakeFromNib method I do the following :-

```
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"ForestMushroom-512"];
[iconView setImage:iconImage]
```

Comment: From the documentation of `iconForFile:`: "Returns an image containing the icon for the specified file.". Have you tried `[NSImage imageNamed:@"ForestMushroom-512"]`?